# Average by value duplicated pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the next csv and I need get the values duplicated from DialedNumer column and then the averege Duration of those duplicates.

[image]

I already got the duplicates with the next code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('cdrs.csv')
dnidump = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['DialedNumber'])
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.0f}'.format
dupl_dni = dnidump.pivot_table(index=['DialedNumber'], aggfunc='size')
a1 = dupl_dni.to_frame().rename(columns={0:'TimesRepeated'}).sort_values(by=['TimesRepeated'], ascending=False)
b = a1.head(10)
print(b)
```

Output:

```
DialedNumber     TimesRepeated
50947740194          4
50936564292          2
50931473242          3
```

I can't figure out how to get the duration avarege of those duplicates, any ideas?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
df_mean = df.groupby('DialedNumber').mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use df.groupby('column').mean()
Here is sample code.

Input

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
                   'B': [2461, 1023, 9, 5614, 212],
                   'C': [2, 4, 8, 16, 32]}, columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
df.groupby('A').mean()
```

Output

```
              B         C
A       
1   1164.333333 4.666667
2   2913.000000 24.000000
```

API reference of pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html